# How can I pass a class name as an argument to an object factory in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, constructor, factory

I am working on an object factory to keep track of a small collection of objects. The objects can be of different types, but they will all respond to `createInstance` and `reset`. The objects can not be derived from a common base class because some of them will have to derive from built-in cocoa classes like `NSView` and `NSWindowController`.

I would like to be able to create instances of any suitable object by simply passing the desired classname to my factory as follows:

```
myClass * variable = [factory makeObjectOfClass:myClass];
```

The `makeObjectOfClass:` method would look something like this:

```
- (id)makeObjectOfClass:(CLASSNAME)className
{
    assert([className instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(reset)]);
    id newInstance = [className createInstance];
    [managedObjects addObject:newInstance];
    return newInstance;
}
```

Is there a way to pass a class name to a method, as I have done with the `(CLASSNAME)className` argument to `makeObjectOfClass:` above?

For the sake of completeness, here is why I want to manage all of the objects. I want to be able to reset the complete set of objects in one shot, by calling `[factory reset];`.

```
- (void)reset
{
    [managedObjects makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(reset)];
}
```

Comment: I'm torn between Michael Tsai's and Matt Gallagher's answers. I upvoted both, since both mention the use of 'Class', which is what I was looking for. In the end, I chose Matt's answer because it emphasizes 'Class' over ClassFromString, and it was the first to mention the use of 'Class' before edits.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: Thank you for changing the tag. For some reason, 'objectivec' shows many more items (around 200) than 'objective-c' in the drop-down list of tags that appears when I added tags to the question, but I now see that 'objectivec' has been redirected to 'objective-c'

Comment: @eJames: Your question shows -reset being sent to instances, not the class object, so I think the [aClass respondsToSelector:@selector(reset)] in Matt Gallagher's answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Michael Tsai: Good catch! I wouldn't have noticed that. Matt must have copied my sample, which has the incorrect method call as well. Thank you for the heads up.

Comment: I have changed the code in my question to use instancesRespondToSelector instead.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can convert a string to a class using the function: NSClassFromString

```
Class classFromString = NSClassFromString(@"MyClass");
```

In your case though, you'd be better off using the Class objects directly.

```
MyClass * variable = [factory makeObjectOfClass:[MyClass class]];

- (id)makeObjectOfClass:(Class)aClass
{
    assert([aClass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(reset)]);
    id newInstance = [aClass createInstance];
    [managedObjects addObject:newInstance];
    return newInstance;
}
```

Comment: The 'Class' type, and [MyClass class] is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Michael Tsai has pointed out that the [aClass respondsToSelector:@selector(reset)] line should instead read [aClass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(reset)]. I am making the change in my question, you may wish to do the same in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have right a better tutorial on that , please checkout
https://appengineer.in/2014/03/13/send-class-name-as-a-argument-in-ios/

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty easy to dynamically specify a class, in fact you can just reference it by it's name:

```
id string = [[NSClassFromString(@"NSString") alloc] initWithString:@"Hello!"];
NSLog( @"%@", string );
```

One other tip, I would avoid using the nomenclature 'managed object' since most other Cocoa programmers will read that as NSManagedObject, from Core Data. You may also find it easier to use a global NSNotification (that all your reset-able objects subscribe to) instead of managing a collection of different types of objects, but you're more informed to make that decision than I am.

Comment: good point about NSManagedObject. I will change my question to avoid the possible confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The bit of the answer missing from the other answers is that you could define a `@protocol` containing your `+createInstance` and `+reset` methods.

Comment: Thank you for the tip! I am planning to use a protocol, but I didn't feel a need to mention it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
- (id)makeObjectOfClassNamed:(NSString *)className
{
    Class klass = NSClassFromString(className);
    assert([klass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(reset)]);
    id newInstance = [klass createInstance];
    [managedObjects addObject:newInstance];
    return newInstance;
}
```

This would assume a class method named `+createInstance`. Or you could just use `[[klass alloc] init]`.

To call it:

```
MyClass *variable = [factory makeObjectOfClassNamed:@"MyClass"];
```

Depending on what you're trying to do, it might be better to pass around class objects than strings, e.g.:

```
MyClass *variable = [factory makeObjectOfClass:[MyClass class]];
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will use the [MyClass class] approach which you mentioned in your edit.

Comment: Unless you are compiling for Objective-C++, you can name variables "class".